# How to restart wildfly host-controller in domain mode efficiently without any risk?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8, application-restart

My companay uses wildfly 8.1.0.Final for middleware and the production system mode is in domain.

For some reason we have to restart the host-controller before auto-deploy.

To resolve this, my workmates always take two ways:

1. kill all java processes , and run the $wildfly_home/start.sh.
   In this way all processes are restarted, but it really takes long.
2. use cli to restart the host-controller with the command: "shutdown --host=master --restart=true".
   This is the common way in out auto-deploy scripts, but takes long either.

Then I was wondering how to restart host-controller only without restarting any other processes.

Finally I tried out one solution: kill -9 ${host-controller pid} (the host-controller process is terminated and the process-controller process forks a new one to take the place of it.)
In this way I successfully restarted the host-controller and I've got "--process-restarted" as a flag for it.

*before restart:*

```
502        454   438  0 19:06 pts/0    00:00:05 /opt/jboss/java64/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java -D[Host Controller] -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/jboss/domain/log/host-controller.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/jboss/domain/configuration/logging.properties -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /opt/jboss/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/jboss/modules org.jboss.as.host-controller -mp /opt/jboss/modules --pc-address 127.0.0.1 --pc-port 43456 -default-jvm /opt/jboss/java64/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java --backup -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/jboss
```

> kill -9 454

*after restart:*

```
502       1080   438 99 19:16 pts/0    00:00:05 /opt/jboss/java64/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java -D[Host Controller] -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/jboss/domain/log/host-controller.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/jboss/domain/configuration/logging.properties -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /opt/jboss/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/jboss/modules org.jboss.as.host-controller -mp /opt/jboss/modules --pc-address 127.0.0.1 --pc-port 43456 -default-jvm /opt/jboss/java64/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java --backup -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/jboss --process-restarted
```

---

I've used this way for several weeks and it seems to work well. So I discussed with my workmates if we could rewrite this restart logic for deploy.
But they wonder if the process-controller will fail to fork a new Host Controller.  Will it happen?

Could any one please tell me if this way have any risk?

If don't could I use it in the auto-deploy scripts for restart?

Comment: What do you mean by "auto-deploy"?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Thanks for replay. I mean doing the deployment all by scripts and one of the steps is to restart the host-controller .   If i want to restart the host-controller by "kill -9", is there any risks or will it cause other exceptions?

Comment: I think it is fine, it might only affect management commands attempted while it is restarting.

Comment: I don't understand why a deployment would cause a need for the host controller to be restarted. Are you executing CLI commands before you deploy?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Two points considered. Firstly we usually make changes in background with modifying the domain.xml or host.xml such as changing a property of  jms or jdbc properties(most of the time i use cli but i can't make anyone use it). On the other hand they think the host-controller will response slower and it seems to be so, though optimize the jvm could relief this. Anyway, suppose I have to restart host-controller, could you give me a suggestion? or would you please tell me how your team deal with it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @eckes  Yes,  it seems to be the least effective way but still a could't persuade others to use it. And if there is a better way I'd like to take it too. Do you have any other solutions?